# Is there an equivalent of Guice Providers in Simple Injector?

Tags: java, c#, dependency-injection, guice, simple-injector

Is there an equivalent injecting Guice Providers in Simple Injector?

I need to inject a dependency into a constructor that will let me create as many instances of a dependency as needed.  In guice it would look like this...

```
public class RealBillingService implements BillingService {
  private final Provider<CreditCardProcessor> processorProvider;
  private final Provider<TransactionLog> transactionLogProvider;

  @Inject
  public RealBillingService(Provider<CreditCardProcessor> processorProvider,
      Provider<TransactionLog> transactionLogProvider) {
    this.processorProvider = processorProvider;
    this.transactionLogProvider = transactionLogProvider;
  }

  public Receipt chargeOrder(PizzaOrder order, CreditCard creditCard) {
    // each call to get creates a new instance in Guice as per scope configs
    CreditCardProcessor processor = processorProvider.get();  
    TransactionLog transactionLog = transactionLogProvider.get();

    /* use the processor and transaction log here */
  }
}
```

So perhaps a C# equivalent could be this inside SimpleInjector?

```
    private readonly MailSender _mailSenderProvider;

    public MailService(Func<MailSender> mailSenderProvider)
    {
        _mailSenderProvider = mailSenderProvider;
    }

    public void SendMail()
    {
        var mailSender = _mailSenderProvider.Invoke();
        mailSender.SendSomeMail("Hello world");
    }
```

I tried injecting Func in my real code and got this...

{"No registration for type BootStrapper could be found and an implicit registration could not be made. The constructor of type BootStrapper contains the parameter of type Func with name 'storeType' that is not registered. Please ensure Func is registered in the container, or change the constructor of BootStrapper."}

Comment: Do you mean a factory? Can you describe your particular situation where you need this?

Comment: I need to inject something that can create new instances of a class as needed.  So imaging I needed to create an instance of a class every time I pass through a loop meeting a condition.  Sometimes I need 1 instance sometimes I need 1000.

Comment: Csn you update your question with the actual code you need? The answer highly depends on your actual use case. What I'm interested in is names of classes. What's the role and function of the class that contains that loop, and what's the name and function of the class you need to create many times.

Comment: i removed c# as this is Java.

Comment: I am asking for a C# equivalent of a Java snippet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the following example in the SimpleInjector docs

http://simpleinjector.readthedocs.org/en/latest/howto.html#register-factory-delegates

```
   public static void AllowResolvingFuncFactories(this ContainerOptions options)
    {
        options.Container.ResolveUnregisteredType += (s, e) =>
        {
            var type = e.UnregisteredServiceType;

            if (!type.IsGenericType || type.GetGenericTypeDefinition() != typeof(Func<>))
            {
                return;
            }

            Type serviceType = type.GetGenericArguments().First();

            InstanceProducer registration = options.Container.GetRegistration(serviceType, true);

            Type funcType = typeof(Func<>).MakeGenericType(serviceType);

            var factoryDelegate = Expression.Lambda(funcType,
                registration.BuildExpression()).Compile();

            e.Register(Expression.Constant(factoryDelegate));
        };
    }
```

Then on my container I call this...

```
        // Allow types of Func<T> to be resolved
        container.Options.AllowResolvingFuncFactories();

        // 3. Optionally verify the container's configuration.
        container.Verify();
```

Now I can inject Func< MyClass > and when I invoke the Func it returns as many instances as I want of that type.

All thanks to C# reified types and Simpleinjector's awesome api!

Answer (score 1):

You need to explicitly configure factory delegates with Simple Injector (see [here](https://simpleinjector.readthedocs.org/en/latest/howto.html#register-factory-delegates))

```
var container = new Container();
container.Register<MailSender>();
container.RegisterSingle<Func<MailSender>>(() => container.GetInstance<MailSender>());
```

You may want to consider separating concerns by adding a new abstraction. If you define an `IMailSender` you can then create a `MailSenderProxy` that is responsible for ensuring a new `MailSender` instance for each message.

```
public interface IMailSender {
    void Send(string message);
}

public class MailSender : IMailSender {
    public void Send(string message) {
    }
}

public class MailSenderProxy : IMailSender {
    private readonly Func<IMailSender> mailSenderFactory;

    public MailSenderProxy(Func<IMailSender> mailSenderFactory) {
        this.mailSenderFactory = mailSenderFactory;
    }

    public void Send(string message) {
        this.mailSenderFactory().Send(message);
    }
}
```

This abstracts away the requirement of creating a new `MailSender` for each mail (this is possibly not something the `MailService` should know about)

```
public class MailService {
    private readonly IMailSender sender;

    public MailService(MailSender sender) {
        this.sender = sender;
    }

    public void SendMail() {
        this.sender.Send("Message");
    }
}
```

The Container configuration would look something like this

```
var container = new Container();
container.Register<MailSender>();
container.RegisterSingle<Func<IMailSender>>(() =>
    container.GetInstance<MailSender>());
container.Register<IMailSender, MailSenderProxy>();
container.Verify();
```